# What is the meaning or function of this notice?

Tags: wp-admin

> Notice: post_permalink is outdated since version 4.4.0! Instead use get_permalink(). in
>   /customers/7/b/f/pzcwesthoek.be/httpd.www/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 3829

Home

De Club

Aanbiedingen

Evenementen

Fotogalerij

Links

Comment: Please post an english version of the error, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

The `post_permalink` is outdated, you need to use the `get_petmalink()`.
Check the follow link for more information: [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)